# How to Plot in a new window in DataSpell

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dataspell

By default, JetBrains DataSpell shows plots inline in Python Console.

Any Idea How to Change this Behavior and Show Plots in a New Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you asking about `SciView` is one of JetBrains' IDEA platform features, specifically designed for scientific purposes.

However, as of now, JetBrains' DataSpell does not support `SciView`. While DataSpell focuses on providing key features for data analysis, some features like SciView have not been incorporated into the IDE.

In the meantime, you can still output your data in the interactive console and use DataSpell's native features for deep data analysis and visual exploration.